# React router automatic redirect on condition

Tags: reactjs

We have an application (widget) that allows users to purchase currency via multiple payment methods. The application consists of multiple steps. Users navigate through the widget steps to finalize the purchase by clicking the `next->next` button.

For example, flow could look like this:

1. select current to purchase
2. login
3. system identifies if you are returning customer and if necessary data already captured skips all steps that are not required such as document verification and payment details
4. if required data is missing system navigates to relevant screen automatically

Customer flow diagram attached:

[image]

I am trying to figure out a clean way to achieve this in react. Initially, I was thinking to delegate responsibility to each screen component to make a decision either to render itself or redirect to another screen but it seems like the entire navigation logic will be distributed across the entire application, which is not ideal.

I think ideally I would like to have a single place in my app where these navigation decisions are made. For example when a customer clicks `Next` application state gets analyzed and the decision is made on what page to render.

Could you please suggest what is the best way to achieve this?

Tech: `react18`, `redux`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **decorator pattern**.
You can read more about it here:

[Decorator design pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/decorator)

Each flow can be abstracted into a function.
Make a function for implementing each stage. Each function needs a callback(s)
which is the next stage function and will be called if the condition is met or not.
In fact, You are chaning function calls. Each function calls the next one.
In the end, you just have one function that needs to be called in your component.

The following diagram can help you understand the solution.

[image: Decorator pattern implementation]